# How to extract elements in specific column of the dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

i have been trying to build a neural network,to do so i have to divide the data into x and y,(my dataset was  converted to numpy).
The data in the "x" is the 1st column which i have extracted successfully but when i try to extract the 2nd column i get the both x and y values for "y".
Here the code i used to divide the data:

```
data=np.genfromtxt("/home/crpsm/Pycharm/DataSet/headbrain.csv",delimiter=',')


x=data[:,:1]
y=data[:, :2]
```

Heres the output of x and y:

x:-

```
[[3738.]
[4261.]
[3777.]
[4177.]
[3585.]
[3785.]
[3559.]
[3613.]
[3982.]
[3443.]
```

y:-

```
[[3738. 1297.]
[4261. 1335.]
[3777. 1282.]
[4177. 1590.]
[3585. 1300.]
[3785. 1400.]
[3559. 1255.]
[3613. 1355.]
[3982. 1375.]
[3443. 1340.]
```

please tell me how to fix this error.Thanks in Advance..!!!

Comment: can you post a dump of your data var? data should be a multi dim array, no? Which is already delimited by ',' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [@w-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463796/w-m) said in t[heir answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52538390/4042267) is correct, you are currently assigning all rows (the first `:`) and all columns, starting from zero up to column one, excluding the upper bound, to `x` (with `:1`) and all rows (again the first `:`) and all columns, starting from zero up to column two, excluding the upper bound, to `y` (with `:2`).

```
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
```

Is one way to do this properly, but a nicer and more succinct way would be to use tuple unpacking:

```
x, y = data.T
```

This transposes (`T) the data, i.e. the two dimensions are exchanged, after which the first dimension has length two. If your actual data has more columns than that, you can use :

```
x, y, *rest = data.T
```

In this case `rest` will be a list of the remaining columns. [This syntax was introduced in Python 3.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to review the numpy indexing [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

To get the second column in the same shape as `x`, use `y=data[:, 1:2]`.

Note: you are creating 2d arrays with this indexing (shape of (len(data), 1)). If you want 1d arrays, just use integers, not slices, for the second term:

```
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
```